# How to read & handle POST requests with Netcat

Tags: bash, http, post, netcat

I want to make a simple HTTP server with Bash & netcat, and have a problem with reading POST requests entirely - the last line is always missing.

The server is started like this:

```
netcat -l -p 8080 -e ./ncserver.sh
```

The `ncserver.sh`, reduced to bare minimum which displays the problem:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while read INPUT; do
    echo "Req line: $INPUT" >&2
done;
```

I use Postman to make requests to the server, and expect the script to dump entire request data to stderr. The request is a simple JSON:

```
{
    name: "Eugene",
    age: 34
}
```

Update:
Raw postman request data:

```
POST /foo/bar HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 7f5a57a7-1664-e79c-2242-7ba6b638e260

{
    name: "Eugene",
    age: 34
}
```

In the server's output I get all the headers and request body which is missing the last line, the `}`. The same holds for other content types, such as `multipart/form-data` - last line is always missing.

Note: if I add an empty line after JSON, I can see the `}` in terminal output.

I tried using `cat /dev/stdin` instead of `read` but get `No such device or address`.

The question probably can be generalized as *how do I read HTTP requests in correct binary form in Bash?*

Comment: What is showing in the raw section of postman? What happens if you use curl? curl -d '{"Name":"Eugene", "age":"34"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST <http://yourserver.com>

Comment: Somehow when I use curl, there is no request body output at all, only headers and two empty lines. The Postman request is very basic, I updated the question with it.

Also, if I add a new line in Postman request body, it kind of works.

Comment: I've tested this with raw and with a bin file and it works in Postman 5.5.4 - google chrome plugin. I'm not using the netcat -e option though. I am redirecting std input nc -l -p 8080 < ncserver.sh

Comment: I guess it's not exactly the same, because I can't respond from the script back to the client, which I eventually would like to do. Also, it seems netcat does the same even if I remove the `< ncserver.sh` part.

Comment: I think the problem boils down to the behaviour of `read` and the fact that it requires a newline as a delimiter, which is not present in request body. Any ideas on how to work it around?

Answer (score 0):

Try as below.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r INPUT || [ "$INPUT" ]; do
    echo "Req line: $INPUT" >&2
done;
```

Point to notice.

`IFS=` is to preserve any indentation.
`-r` is to prevent backslash interpretation.
Check for `INPUT`: When  `read` reaches the end-of-file instead of end-of-line it assigns variable but exits. hence, check if we have anything in `INPUT`.

Comment: The thing is, there is no EOF in the data coming from nc, if I do `nc -o reqdata`, I can see that the latest character is `}`, so setting IFS won't do anything here. It seems the only way for me is to `read -n1`, which has it's own flaws...

Comment: Give the above script a try

Comment: Solution to the issue lies in check of `INPUT`. Its good to use `IFS=` and `-r` here.

Comment: I did try it of course, the result is exactly same.

Comment: What does `[ "$INPUT" ]` mean? Is there a `sh` version of it?

Answer (score 0):

Hello @x1n13y84issmd42

Just in case you are still looking for a solution..
I had good results when trying the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -d } PAYLOAD;
```

Instead of parsing each line as they come, the "-d }" option makes read store everything that comes through stdin in PAYLOAD until it meets "}".

You can then process $PAYLOAD} with jq for instance

Comment: What if it have other objects that starts with `{` and (IMPORTANT) ends with `}`, such as arrays?

Comment: Unfortunately this workaround doesn't work with nested JSON :(